# discord.py how do i get seperate prefixes for seperate servers with te prefixes stored in an sqlite db

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py, bots

Alright so I've got a discord.py bot. And I want it to have a custom prefix for every server but I don't know how to do that in sqlite, I know decent sql and average python so I should be able to understand the answers. I've created a table with guild_id and prefix as columns but I don't know how to set a default prefix before the custom prefix is set. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you just tried to store the guild id with your default prefix in the database when the bot joins a new guild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no one here is going to give you the code to it by creating a table and have unique guild_id and have their prefix as varchar with some length then once the bot enters a server give them a default prefix and then have a command that will update that prefix in the DB

Comment: I didn't ask for a source code, I simply asked for help. I said that I have the database and custom prefixes ready, I just needed help with the default prefix.